# URL rewriting. More than one htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've more than one .htaccess file. In a folder /user I have .htaccess file with a next content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and that works perfectly. When visitor type /user/ID he actually call php script index.php with specific ID.

Now I create subfolder in a user folder and have structure like this:
/user/json

and what I need is that when visitor type /user/ID/json to call index.php script which is in json folder with specific ID.

Maybe I am thinking wrong.

Please, any kind of help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: More information are below

Here I have situation when I type

/user/5 (I got user with ID = 5)
/user/100 (I got user with ID = 100)

That works perfectly and I made it on a way that I added .htaccess file and index.php in /user/.

Now I want to get results in json on the next way:
When I type /user/5/json I want to get user with ID = 5. If I type /user/100/json I want user with ID = 100.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put another .htaccess in /user/ID/json and just change the line:

```
ReWriteBase /user/
```

to

```
ReWriteBase /user/ID/json/
```

Comment: But what that mean? Do you understand mine question? I want to enable to user get output in json when type /user/ID/json where ID can be any number 1..10..100 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Add this new rule in `/user/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/json/?$ json/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Make sure there is no .htaccess in json directory**

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?([A-Z][a-z])+$ index.php?id=$1&format=$2 [L,QSA]

I haven't tested this, though.